# Unable to send requests from localhost:3000 to localhost:5000 all of a sudden

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors

My project uses a Springboot backend and React frontend. All of a sudden, the requests stopped working. I have been using this project for months.

This is the request that is failing:

```
  // authenticate
  // API_BASE_URL in this case is http://localhost:5000/api/
  async authenticateUser(user) {
    return axios.post(API_BASE_URL + "authenticate", user).catch((error) => {
      console.log("failed to authenticate user: " + error);
      throw new Error("failed to authenticate user");
    });
  }
```

The backend code for that endpoint looks like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/api/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getEmail(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password");
        }

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getEmail());
        final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));

    }
```

And this is my `SecurityConfiguration` class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    MongoUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/api/register",
                        "/api/authenticate", "/api/test")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // create bean of type 'authenticationManager'
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;

    }
}
```

Adding photos so that you can see the issues visually.

As you can see in the image below, its failing the Preflight, but why?
[image: CORS failed]

Here is the corss-origin request data:
[image: CORS2]

And here is the Options request:
[image: CORS3]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the `@CrossOrigin(origins = { "*" })` that I have on my `AuthenticationController` class was not working as expected.

To fix, I added the line `config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));` to the `corsConfigurationSource` so that it looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;

    }
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, don't hesitate to accept your own answer.